# Locking an axis for a curve

Tags: bezier-curves

How would I lock an axis for a curve? I don't want the curve to go in a certain direction until I unlock it. I'm frequently finding that when I created a beveled curve, what looks like everything is on the same level, is actually higher and lower on the Z-Axis.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the curve shape to *2D* in *Curve > Shape* until you want to adjust it in Z axis:

[image]

Note that you will still be able to rotate the curve in *Object Mode*, so you can use this to lock the curve in any direction.

Another option is to fix the curve afterwards:

1. Select all the control points (<kbd>A</kbd>):

   [image]
2. Scale to `0` on the axis you want to lock. E.g. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>
   This will scale everything to be on a plane with the [*Pivot point*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point), so you can easily control this by using the 3D cursor:

   [image]